# North Indian ocean tropical cyclones

Tags: meteorology, tropical-cyclone

Why are tropical cyclones in the Bay of Bengal more frequent and stronger than those in the Arabian Sea?

Comment: I agree.  But I would like to know is there  connections between cyclones and salinity in Bay of Bengal (It is less saline than Arabian sea )and the influence of river deltas in Bay of Bengal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

During the Indian Summer Monsoon, a low level jet covers the Arabian Sea. This causes vertical wind shear to increase over the Arabian Sea and inhibits cyclogenesis in the region. Hence, less tropical cyclone activity compared to the Bay of Bengal.

http://www.meted.ucar.edu/tropical/textbook_2nd_edition/print_3.htm#page_5.3.0
(Need account to login)
http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v479/n7371/full/nature10552.html#ref1
(First line)